# Организация данных в приложении андроид

Tags: java, android, проектирование, данные

Делаю игру, смысл которой отгадывать страну по ее флагу.
Для приложения использую ресурсы картинок и строки с названиями. В коде создаю два массива для этих данных со строгим соблюдением последовательности для дальнейшего доступа к ним по индексу (только чтение). Смотрел в сторону Enum, но ведь каждый его элемент является объектом , считаю этот вариант более накладной по производительности чем массив
 Подскажите пожалуйста лучшее решение.
 P.S.  с бд пока незнаком.

Comment: *"этот вариант более накладной по производительности"* - ну вы же используете java, да еще и на android, значит на производительность положен такой болт, что какой-либо эффект от лишнего енумератора можно разве что под микроскопом. Ну а вообще, приводите код, а то что чего вам там понадобился этот енумератор - из вопроса не ясно.

Comment: Ну с Котлин пока не знаком, поэтому джава. Кода много, постараюсь изложить смысл: на макете есть картинка и 4 кнопки с вариантами ответа, нужно рандомно выводить картинку и варианты ответа, с одним правильным. Для работы с ресурсами закидываю их в массивы, чтоб реализовать логику случайного вывода используя индексы массивов, но есть проблема, если я в дальнейшем изменю какой нибудь массив, то получится бяка. Вот и спрашиваю какие есть ещё варианты организации данных. Пока писал ответ задумался о создании объекта "страна", вдруг мне понадобится в дальнейшем добавить описание страны.ваше мнеие

Comment: Ну котлин только добавляет оверхеда. *"Кода много, постараюсь изложить смысл"* - приводите [mcve].

Comment: Так и каждый `String` - тоже объект. И вообще Java - объектно ориентированный язык. Если для задачи критична производительность, то писать лучше на ассемблере и использовать аппаратные примочки. Если не настолько, чтобы во всё это вникать, то обычная программа на Java пишется с ориентацией на удобство, переносимость, расширяемость, переиспользование и т.п.  Объект "страна" - правильная мысль. И в коде удобнее оперировать, и расширяемость закладывается, и сериализовать проще (хранить в БД, JSON, XML, etc., пересылать по сети). Enum - по сути тот же класс, но с константным числом экземпляров.

Comment: `enum` как раз лучше подходит для такой задачи, так как фактически перечисление позволит инкапсулировать массив объектов типа страна

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Это структура данных вида ключ-значение. Тогда не придется беспокоиться о порядке.

Пример:

```
HashMap<String, String> flags = new HashMap<String, String>();
flags.put("Albania", "путь к ресурсу");
flags.put("Bulgaria", "путь к ресурсу");
flags.put("Croatia", "путь к ресурсу");
flags.put("Denmark", "путь к ресурсу");
```

Ключ - название страны, значение - путь к ресурсу с изображением флага.

Получить путь к флагу по названию страны очень просто

```
path = flags.get("Albania");
```

На русском немного [тут](https://javarush.com/groups/posts/1940-klass-hashmap-), например.

Для получения случайного ключа нет прямого способа, можно сделать так. Сначала создать список из ключей:

```
Set<String> keysSet = flags.keySet();
String[] keysArray = keysSet.toArray(new String[keysSet.size()]);
```

Потом брать из него случайное значение:

```
path = flags.get(keysArray[random.nextInt(keysSet.size())]);
```

От массива, правда, избавиться не удалось. Зато удалось избавиться от необходимости поддерживания двух массивов в одном порядке.

Comment: А как организовать логику получения рандомного ключа или значения? В приложении я вывожу случайную картинку и 4 варианта названия стран в том числе одно верное

Comment: А как вы сейчас получаете случайную картинку?

Comment: Что-то типа: `flagsArray[random.nextInt()]`

Comment: @Эникейщик, это всё замечательно - вот только автор не просил избавиться от массивов а сомневается в производительности своей сотни строк кода, которые он нам даже не показал. Поэтому получается, что в качестве ответа нужно исследование по производительности для всех вариантов подобных задач))) А задача простейшая - квест с флагом и ответами названиями стран

Comment: Ну главный вопрос, как бы, в целостности данных вдруг в массив имён добавлю новое, в результате индексы перестанут соответствовать друг-другу

Comment: В этом решении у данных нет индексов, поэтому и такой проблемы нет.